# Is there any way to using built-in Python libraries to specify what the keys of a returned dictionary are using type hints?

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there any way to using built-in Python libraries (e.g. `Typing`, `__future__.annotations`) to specify what the keys of a returned dictionary are with type hints?

I want to do something like this:

```
def foo() -> dict["key1": set(), "key2": bool, "key3": int]:
  ...code stuff...
  return my_dict
```

Comment: Sounds like you should encapsulate it into a class instead.

Comment: Thanks for the style suggestion, but that's not really what I'm looking for. Although I ultimately ended up choosing a different implementation, I was still curious about whether the feature I mentioned in my question was possible.